# JUNG - adding an edge or a node dynamically in a graph

Tags: jung

I use Java and Jung for an application with graphs. I want to add dynamically an edge to a graph while it is visible. In particular, I choose a node from a list (JComboBox) and when I press a button an edge shall be created between that node and a given node. However, when I do that I get a 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
message.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post a stack trace.  Also, have you looked at the sample code for the graph editor demo?